How can i pass in coords to draw the correct shape on an IMAGE?
can I pass actual x / y cords to Leaflet.js to draw a shape? - I have tried using actual cords and the shape is nothing like I expect - also SetView cords can I pass them here too ?
Code:

var map = L.map('map').setView([86, 18], 0);

// The values below are the exact x y coords - but when passing them the drawing is nothing like the correct shape

var coordinates = [
    [86, 18],
    [1896, 62],
    [1909, 612],
    [62, 568],
    [68, 45]
];

Expected a Rectangle shape however I get only 3 sides and a lot smaller

Please add enough (relevant) code to create a [mre]

Do read https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html
